# Get list of unique combination between many to many SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables (postgres) connected as @Many-to-many between each other.

**Table A**:

- ID: integer

**Table B**:

- ID: integer

**Intermediate table C**:

- ID: integer
- Table A ID: integer
- Table B ID: integer

What I need to do is:

- for **each Table A** value find all connected Table B values
- for **each founded table B value** find **all unique combination** of Table A values.

Example:

- Table A has value with ID 1;
- Value with ID 1 from Table A connected to table B values with ID 1,2,3,4,5;
- (A1 -> B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)
- From other side value with id 1 from table B connected to ids 1,2 from table A
- (B1 -> A1,A2) -> this is first unique combination
- (B2 -> A1,A3) -> second unique combination
- (B3 -> A1,A2,A3) -> third unique combination
- (B4 -> A2,A1) -> NOT unique combination because we have example 1
- (B5 -> A1,A2) -> NOT unique combination because we have example 1

**Table A contains about 200 values. Each A value connected to ± 10.000 table B values.**
**What have I done**:

In a loop get values for each Table A value

```
select b1.id
from b b1
         right join c c1 on b1.id = c1.b_id
where c1.a_id = ?;
```

For each table B value getting all table A values:

```
select a1.id
from a a1
         right join c c1 on a1.id = c1.a1_id
  where c1.b1_id in (values from prev request)
```

Then put result to hashmap (dict) to store only unique.

1. What if more efficient way to get right result?
2. Is there a way to get not unique combination but ALL combination in 1 query?

Answer (score 1):

A simple join provides the `ID` from `B` table connected with table `A`. You use distinct to show each key only once even if there are more connections.

```
select distinct c.b_id  from a
join c on a.id = c.a_id
order by 1;

b_id|
----+
   1|
   2|
   3|
   4|
   5|
```

using the above result as a CTE you join back to table `A`

```
with bb as ( 
select distinct c.b_id  from a
join c on a.id = c.a_id
)
select distinct bb.b_id, c.a_id
from bb
join c on bb.b_id = c.b_id
order by 1,2;

b_id|a_id|
----+----+
   1|   1|
   1|   2|
   2|   1|
   2|   3|
   3|   1|
   3|   2|
   3|   3|
   4|   1|
   4|   2|
   5|   1|
   5|   2|
```

using string_agg you concatenates the IDs to a list

```
with bb as ( 
select distinct c.b_id  from a
join c on a.id = c.a_id
),
tot as (
select distinct bb.b_id, c.a_id
from bb
join c on bb.b_id = c.b_id
)
select b_id,
string_agg(a_id::text,',' order by a_id) a_lst
from tot
group by 1 order by 1
;  

b_id|a_lst|
----+-----+
   1|1,2  |
   2|1,3  |
   3|1,2,3|
   4|1,2  |
   5|1,2  |
```

and simple gets the distinct values

```
with bb as ( 
select distinct c.b_id  from a
join c on a.id = c.a_id
),
tot as (
select distinct bb.b_id, c.a_id
from bb
join c on bb.b_id = c.b_id
),
agg as (
select b_id,
string_agg(a_id::text,',' order by a_id) a_lst
from tot
group by 1)
select distinct a_lst
from agg
order by 1
;  

a_lst|
-----+
1,2  |
1,2,3|
1,3  |
```